# Nonvanishing radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Assume that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ has a *nonvanishing* radius of convergence. Find a power series representation for $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1-x}$.

What does *nonvanishing* even mean?

Comment: nonvanishing is a fancy term for nonzero (hence, in this context, it means positive, possibly +infinity)

Comment: you know the power series for 1/(1-x), right?

Answer (score 1):

Power series representation for $g$:

For $|x|<1$ we have $\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$

If $R>0$ is radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, then

$g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$ for $|x|< \min\{1,R\}$.

Its your turn to determine the numbers $c_n$. Hint: Cauchy product.